# Broken Screen on S6 Active. How to pull files from it?

Tags: adb, screen, images

My friend has given me his S6 Active to pull photos from, so he can put them on his new phone. The screen has no display, and USB debugging is NOT enabled. When plugged into the pc with a charging cable, and a data cable, it still is not recognized by the pc. I would like to pull photos from this device, as there has to be a way.

I cant use ADB commands, as it is not showing up in the pc.
I cannot use a mouse and keyboard, as there is still no display. 
I can't access anything on the phone, unless the pc recognizes it.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

In normal scene it should be recognized in pc but some OEM have their phones such way that it won't be detected till it is locked

So try to see if it is unlocked and when you are sure that its unlocked connect it to PC then on guess work you can select the usb settings from notifications and click MTP and to do so refer to s6 usb/MTP settings  videos(youtube) and tap exactly at the screen as in videos and you should get it

Answer (score 0):

Tell your friend to get her screen repaired and next time she shouldn't forget to set up drive and Google photos